# What's wrong with this code html5 video and mysql

Tags: php, mysql, html, video

i have a namefile stored on mysql , what i want to do is give that name to a html5 video tag , so the videos automatically pop up when i insert them on mysql and are on the website already. this is what i've done :

```
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "****";
$password = "****";
$dbname = "***";
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
if (!$conn) {
die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
$sql ="SELECT enlace FROM series";
```

The result of that query is as follows :

```
Blindspot.S01E01  
Continuum.S04E0   
Continuum.S04E01  
Continuum.S04E02  
Continuum.S04E03  
doctorwhos09
```

Then what i do is this :

```
$result = $conn->query($sql);
<?php 

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
// output data of each row

while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo "<video controls>";
    echo '<source src="series/'.$row["enlace"].' type="video/webm"/>';

    echo " </video>";
    echo $row["enlace"];



}} else {echo "0 results";}$conn->close();


?>
```

It displays 6 video players , but says no video was found by that name

Answer (score 2):

Missed `"` after `src` -

```
echo '<source src="series/'.$row["enlace"].'" type="video/webm"/>';
```

Comment: Not wrong! How do I supposed to know what should the value in it. Pointed out the error only. Rest its yours. :)

Answer (score 0):

found the error

```
echo '<source src="series/'.$row["enlace"].'.webm" type="video/webm"/>';
```

I did not specify video format.